# Django 1.7 Admin - How to hide timezone warning?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.7

I upgraded to Django 1.7 recently, and I'm starting to see these timezone warnings on DateTime/Time fields when my local timezone differs from the server timezone when I view them in the admin interface. I definitely understand why they added this, and it remove a lot of ambiguity, especially with DateTime, but I have a TimeField that actually stores time respective to the logged-in user's timezone (as saved on their user profile), so the warning message is actually misleading in that case. I've also seen that it is indeed Django 1.7 that has added this functionality (see https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js#L63 and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#admin-shortcuts-support-time-zones).

My question is how do I turn off these messages from showing? If so, is there a way I can specify how to hide the warnings on a per-field basis?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you add a `Media` class to your `ModelAdmin` you can include a CSS file that makes those warnings disappear.

```
# admin.py
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = MyModel
    
    class Media(object):
        css = {'all': ('no-more-warnings.css', )}
```

The created CSS file should include the following rule:

```
/* no-more-warnings.css */
.timezonewarning {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I'm using Django 2.2 and this solution unfortunately no longer works. :(

Comment: @AdamY works fine for me on Django 3.2 :O

Comment: My initial comment misunderstood the answer. This works. Many thanks to @ruohola for explaining it to me.

I had assumed no-more-warnings.css was part of the Django admin and setting the Media class attribute simply enabled it. That is not the case. One must create a file called no-more-warnings.css and put the suggested CSS into it. The Media class will then load that CSS file as part of your model admin setup.

Answer (score 0):

I added this code to a js file which loads in all of the pages in my application.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   // override django 1.7 timezone warning
   DateTimeShortcuts.addTimezoneWarning = function(){return false;};
});
```